# how to source csh script from bash environment?

Tags: bash, source, csh

I am using bash shell but some of the scripts that I need to source are in csh format. Can somebody tell how I can source csh scripts from bash shell?

By sourcing I mean the sourced csh script should be able to set the environment variables. So, I want to do something like this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
source path/to/csh_script/script.cshrc
```

Comment: Depending on what the script does, it might be impossible.

Comment: @muru one could use awk to convert csh syntax of alias and variable to bash, right ?

Comment: @Serg One could use a lot of things. But it maybe that there are csh features that have no bash equivalents. I don't know. Good luck writing a csh to bash compiler in awk.

Answer (score 2):

bash won't run all csh scripts perfectly. There may be some basic overlap, like very basic bash scripts will run in sh/dash, but if it fails to run in bash (test with `bash [file]` ) then it's a no-go. Either

- modify them to run in bash, or
- run them with csh, called from the bash script, as if you're running them in a terminal, having them return a result value or do whatever they're supposed to. This would not leave any variables or functions available to the main bash script, as you've commented, so you'll either

  - have them do whatever they're supposed to do to external files, or
  - return a single value/string, or maybe
  - treat them like another program and read multiple lines of output into your bash script.

If you're just looking to source variables, it's theoretically possible to go through the csh script line-by-line and adding just the variables into the current bash shell/script. Something similar to this:

```
while read line
do
[stuff with $line]
done < /path/to/[the csh script to add]
```

I don't know how all the variables are laid out in the scripts you're sourcing, so it's up to you to decide what the [stuff with $line] should be.

- If they're like **bash**, then maybe just grep any lines that begin with spaces or characters, have a `=` with optionally more characters with no spaces, so:

  echo "$line" | `grep '^\s*\S*=\S*'`
- or as above with anything after the `=` with:

  echo "$line" | `grep '^\s*\S*=.*'`

But I [think](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcsh-csh-c_shell-set-variable-command/) csh variables all start with `set` / `setenv`, so could find set/setenv lines, then throw out the set/setenv. Try as a starter:

```
echo "$line" | grep '^\s*\S*set.*=.*'
```

Those're just quick sample grep / regex patterns, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642246/how-to-grep-using-a-variable-in-bash) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676714/grep-match-all-characters-up-to-not-including-first-blank-space#14676732) & [others](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) for more info.

Or, if it's only a few of them, go through them manually & paste all the variables into bash/sh compatible files you can then source in bash with no problems.

Comment: That's right. csh is a different language. You wouldn't expect bash to understand C or Python or ...

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line already takes care of that for you. When you run a script that has `#! /bin/csh -f` as first line, the system will recognize `#!` part as script, and load whatever interpreter is specified after it (in this case `/bin/csh`).

Alternatively, you could call the interpreter explicitly , with `csh /path/to/script.csh`.

Here's a small demo. My interactive shell is `mksh` and I am calling a simple `csh` script:

```
xieerqi:
$ cat bin/whiledemo.csh                                                                       
#! /bin/csh -f 
# demoloop.csh - Sample loop script 
set j = 1
 while ( $j <= 5 )
   echo "Welcome $j times"
   @ j++
 end

xieerqi:
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/mksh

xieerqi:
$ bin/whiledemo.csh                                                                           
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times

xieerqi:
$ csh bin/whiledemo.csh                                                                       
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
```

Note that if you have even one space in front of `#!` , the `#!` won't be interpreted, hence the script will run with your interactive shell from which you call the script. Naturally, you can expect script to fail due to different syntax between script and what interactive shell expects. In the process of writing this answer, I encountered this exact error.

Comment: But I want to set the environment variables from the cshrc script. You method works for running the scripts but the variables set in that script will be lost after the execution of that script. I am asking how to source the csh script ( i.e. run it in the same shell not a child shell )

Comment: @NitishSrivastava sourcing is not possible , as far as I can tell. Syntax of `bash` is different than `csh` so any function defined in `.cshrc` file will likely be unintelligible to

Answer (score 0):

I don't know csh but I have a similar requirement for ksh. My hack solution was to

```bash
eval source <(ksh -c ". /path/to/my_script.ksh
env|sort)
```

I ran into issues with quoting and ended up putting in some grep patterns after the env to remove environment variables that I didn't want carried over but it kinda worked.

I found another useful bit here:

https://www.theunixschool.com/2010/07/how-to-access-child-shell-env-variable.html

This little bit of sed creates properly quoted export commands:

```bash
sed 's/^/export /;s/=/=\"/;s/$/\"/'
```